# how to find the limit of $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\Big(\ln\frac{1}{x}\Big)^x$?

Tags: limits

Given limit, I am confused with L'hopital's rules here due to existing $\ln$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\Big(\ln\frac{1}{x}\Big)^x$$

Comment: Please include additional context.  Perhaps explain what you know about l'Hopital's rule and why this doesn't fit the rule.

Comment: Try this $\ln (1/x) = e^{\ln (\ln (1/x))}$. Now use L'Hopital's rule in the exponent.

Comment: note that $$\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\ln(1)-\ln(x)=-\ln(x)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: write your limit in the form $$e^{\frac{\ln(-\ln(x))}{\frac{1}{x}}}$$
and use L'Hospital